# spring mvc - parameter passing from jsp to controller - page redirect

Tags: spring-mvc, parameter-passing, http-redirect

I've a spring web application. I'm passing a parameter from `controllerA` to  `jsp1.jsp` page. This page after 5sec will redirect to `jsp2.jsp`. During the redirect the request goes through `controllerA`. I would like to know how do I pass the parameter from jsp1.jsp to controllerA.
here is my `controllerA` method

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/jsp2", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public String jsp2(ModelMap model) {

    // code to access the parameter from jsp1.jsp

    return "/pages/jsp2";
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Depends on how you are passing the parameter. If you are passing it as a query parameter, you can access it like below

```
@RequestMapping(value="/jsp2", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public String jsp2(@RequestParam("param") String param, ModelMap model) {
    log.info("Got parameter " + param);
    return "/pages/jsp2";
 }
```